# apache subdomain configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, domain, subdomain

I seem to be having a small problem with setting up a subdomain in apache under CentOS.

I have the following:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName www.domain.co.uk
  ServerAlias domain.co.uk dev.domain.co.uk
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/domain/web"
   DirectoryIndex index.php
   Alias /sf /var/www/html/symfony14/web/sf

 <Directory "/var/www/html/domain/web">
   AllowOverride All
   Allow from All
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/var/www/html/symfony14/web/sf">
 AllowOverride All
 Allow from All
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName test.domain.co.uk
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/domain_test/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  Alias /sf /var/www/html/symfony14/web/sf

  <Directory "/var/www/html/domain_test/web">
   AllowOverride All
   Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So going to www.domain.co.uk and domain.co.uk display the contents from /var/www/html/domain, but going to test.domain.co.uk also displays the same folder contents.

Is this because of the `ServerAlias` ?

Thanks

**UPDATED:**

Added missing directive `NameVirtualHost *:80`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting `NameVirtualHost *:80`  as first line in your config file.

You can configure sub-domain by [name based virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost) entries in httpd.conf. To use name-based virtual hosting, you must designate the IP address (and possibly port) on the server that will be accepting requests for the hosts. This is configured using the [NameVirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost) directive.

For more information refer [Subdomain Configuration](http://content.websitegear.com/article/subdomain_setup.htm).

Comment: I have added that, but the sudomain is still pointing at the main domains `web` folder.

Comment: That seemed to work. I removed the <Directory></Directory> part in between the two vhosts as well. All seems to be working now!

Answer (score 0):

Well they should be showing the same content since the DocumentRoot is the same.

I suppose for the test domain it should have been `DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/domain_test/web"`  instead of `DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/domain/web"`

Comment: I have updated the vhost, but the problem is still happening. Do subdomains need to be before the full domain?

Comment: No, the order of the directives plays no role at all. Did you restart Apache after the configuration changes?

Comment: Yes I did. But this hasn't changed anything.

Comment: Something else then is messing up. 
Is that the whole of your .conf file? 
Do you have enabled Named virtual hosts?

Upload the whole of your conf file and not just this part